# .NET Core 2.1 + Identity as UI + windows service - how to set port?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Background: with a bit of play I managed to set up .NET Core 2.1 + Identity as UI + windows service (following [this](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-scaffold-identity-ui-in-asp-net-core-2-1/) article) like this:

- install .NET Core 2.1 Preview 2 SDK
- install Visual Studio 2017 Preview
- dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices --version 2.1.0-rc1-final
- New Project -> '.NET Core' ->  'ASP.NET Core Web Application' -> OK
- select ASP.NET Core 2.1 (at the top) -> Web Application
  Deselect 'Configure for HTTPS
  'Change Authentication' -> 'Individual User Accounts' -> OK
- In Program.cs:
  Add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices;`

  replace 
   `CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();` 
  with:

  ```
  if (Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--debug"))
  {
      CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
  }
  else
  {
      CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsService();
  }
  ```
- in Startup.cs:
  remark `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`
- In launchSettings.json: 
  Replace:

  `"MyProj": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  }`

  with:

  `"MyProj": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44322;http://localhost:44322",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
    }
  }`

(I think that was all)

I then Rebuild Solution and in the project directory do:

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r win-x64
```

I get `MyProj\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\win-x64\MyProj.exe` which I install as a service and run it

In Chrome I then:

`http://localhost:5000/` - works :)
`http://localhost:44322/` - does not work :(

That is the port settings from launchSettings.json were not applied

How do I get the service to listen on http 44322 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`launchSettings.json` is only used for development settings interpreted by `dotnet run` or Visual Studio.

In production, you can set the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable or launch using `MyProj.exe --urls "http://localhost:5020;https://localhost:5021"`.

Alternatively, you can also call `.UseUrls("…")` on the web host builder:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("…")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
```